# Python+Pandas - Determining Months of Inactivity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that has:

```
Columns = "Chronological Months"
Index = "Customer ID's"
Data = "Dollars Spent By Customer"
```

I want to create a new column that indicates how many consecutive months each client has been inactive (with those who spent $ in the most recent month having a 0 value). I'm only interested in the last 6 months.

I can think of a few ways to do this that are really inefficient (for example, a string of IF statements applied to vectors), but I'm hoping to avoid them.

Image of what I'm envisioning is below.

[image]

Comment: Are those `NaN` blanks? then `df['inactive'] = df.bfill(1).isnull().sum(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bfill` with `axis=1` (along the columns) and `isnull` then `sum(axis=1)`  to get count

```
In [14]: df.bfill(axis=1).isnull().sum(axis=1)
Out[14]:
Cusomter 1     5
Cusomter 2     6
Cusomter 3     1
Cusomter 4     5
Cusomter 5     0
Cusomter 6     3
Cusomter 7     6
Cusomter 8     2
Cusomter 9     3
Cusomter 10    0
dtype: int64

In [15]: df['Months of Inactivity'] = df.bfill(axis=1).isnull().sum(axis=1)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
               Jan    Feb    Mar  April    Mat   June  Months of Inactivity
Cusomter 1   300.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                     5
Cusomter 2     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                     6
Cusomter 3     NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN                     1
Cusomter 4   300.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                     5
Cusomter 5     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  300.0                     0
Cusomter 6     NaN    NaN  200.0    NaN    NaN    NaN                     3
Cusomter 7     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                     6
Cusomter 8   100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN                     2
Cusomter 9     NaN    NaN  400.0    NaN    NaN    NaN                     3
Cusomter 10  300.0    NaN    NaN  200.0  100.0  100.0                     0
```

---

If blank cells are `-` hyphens, use `replace`

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
             Jan  Feb  Mar April  Mat June
Cusomter 1   300    -    -     -    -    -
Cusomter 2     -    -    -     -    -    -
Cusomter 3     -  100    -     -  100    -
Cusomter 4   300    -    -     -    -    -
Cusomter 5     -    -    -     -    -  300
Cusomter 6     -    -  200     -    -    -
Cusomter 7     -    -    -     -    -    -
Cusomter 8   100    -    -   100    -    -
Cusomter 9     -    -  400     -    -    -
Cusomter 10  300    -    -   200  100  100

In [32]: df['Inactivity'] = df.replace('-', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).isnull().sum(axis=1)

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
             Jan  Feb  Mar April  Mat June  Inactivity
Cusomter 1   300    -    -     -    -    -           5
Cusomter 2     -    -    -     -    -    -           6
Cusomter 3     -  100    -     -  100    -           1
Cusomter 4   300    -    -     -    -    -           5
Cusomter 5     -    -    -     -    -  300           0
Cusomter 6     -    -  200     -    -    -           3
Cusomter 7     -    -    -     -    -    -           6
Cusomter 8   100    -    -   100    -    -           2
Cusomter 9     -    -  400     -    -    -           3
Cusomter 10  300    -    -   200  100  100           0
```

Comment: Very slick. Personally, I like explicitly writing out the axis parameter. I'm sure beginners would be confused about `bfill(1)`

Comment: Thanks Zero, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try `last_valid_index`

```
d['Months of Inactivity']=6-d.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index, axis=1).map(dict(zip(list(d), list(range(1,d.shape[1]+1))))).fillna(0)
d
Out[221]: 
              Jan    Feb    Mar  April    Mat   June  Months of Inactivity
Cusomter1   300.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                   5.0
Cusomter2     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                   6.0
Cusomter3     NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN                   1.0
Cusomter4   300.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                   5.0
Cusomter5     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  300.0                   0.0
Cusomter6     NaN    NaN  200.0    NaN    NaN    NaN                   3.0
Cusomter7     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN                   6.0
Cusomter8   100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN                   2.0
Cusomter9     NaN    NaN  400.0    NaN    NaN    NaN                   3.0
Cusomter10  300.0    NaN    NaN  200.0  100.0  100.0                   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is crucial you can drop down into numpy and get nearly two orders of magnitude speed up.

```
a=np.where(df.values != '-', 1, 0)
np.append(a[:, ::-1], np.ones((len(a),1)), axis=1).argmax(axis=1)

array([5, 6, 1, 5, 0, 3, 6, 2, 3, 0])
```

*speed tests*

```
%%timeit
a=np.where(df.values != '-', 1, 0)
np.append(a[:, ::-1], np.ones((len(a),1)), axis=1).argmax(axis=1)
24.4 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit df.replace('-', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).isnull().sum(axis=1)
1.91 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Could you add `df.shape` used in the tests?